# How to read characters from a text file, then store them into a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am working on an assignment, and can't figure it out. We have to first parse a text file, and then feed the results into a hash.  I have done this:

```
    code = File.open(WORKING_DIR + '/code.txt','r')
    char_count = {'a' => 0,'b' => 0,'c' => 0,'d' => 0,'e' => 0,'f' => 0,'g' => 0,'h' => 0,'i' => 0,
                   'j' => 0,'k' => 0,'l' => 0,'m' => 0,'n' => 0,'o' => 0,'p' => 0,'q' => 0,'r' => 0,
                   's' => 0,'t' => 0,'u' => 0,'v' => 0,'w' => 0,'x' => 0,'y' => 0,'z' => 0
                   }
# Step through each line in the file.
code.readlines.each do |line|

    # Print each character of this particular line.
    line.split('').each do
        |ch| 
            char_count.has_key?('ch')
                char_count['ch'] +=1        
           end
```

My line of thinking: open the file to a variable named code
read the individual lines
break the lines into each character.
I know this works, I can puts out the characters to screen.
Now I need to feed the characters into the hash, and it isn't working.  I am struggling with the syntax (at least) and basic concepts (at most). I only want the alphabet characters, not the punctuation, etc. from the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Pst...if you open a File like that, you'd better close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would directly do :

```
File.open(WORKING_DIR + '/code.txt','r') do |f|
   char_count = Hash.new(0) # create a hash where 0 is the default value
   f.each_char do |c| # iterate on each character
      ... # some filter on the character you want to reject.
      char_count[c] +=1
   end
end
```

PS : you wrote `'ch'` the string instead of `ch` the variable name

EDIT : the filter could be

```
f.each_char do |c| # iterate on each character
   next if c ~= \/W\ # exclude with a regexp non word character
   ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using Enumerable class methods:

```
    open("file").each_char.grep(/\w/).group_by { |char| 
        char 
    }.each { |char,num| 
        p [char, num.count] 
    }
```

(The grep method filter is using regex "\w" (any character, digit ou underscore); you can change to [A-Za-z] for filter only alphabets.)

Comment: Thanks Carlos, appreciate it. I don't use Ruby at all anymore, but a big +1 for answering something that is so buried! You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
char_count.has_key?('ch')
  char_count['ch'] +=1        
end
```

You're not using the variable but a string `'ch'`, change that in both places for `ch`.

Also the hash could be created using range, for example:

```
char_count = {}
('a'..'z').each{|l| char_count[l] = 0}
```

or:

```
char_count = ('a'..'z').inject({}){|hash,l| hash[l] = 0 ; hash}
```